# Horizontal navigation menu that doesn't wrap

Tags: navigation, css-float

I am having trouble creating an inline navigation menu that does not "wrap" when the browser resizes. Whatever I try (containers, min-width, etc.) it looks remarkably different in...you guessed it, IE (testing with IE8, also using latest FF and Chrome). I am a novice, please pardon the mess. The site is

http://robertdwatkins.com

*Note:* a logo is styled with CSS and floats in a separate div to the left of the naviagtion so they line up.

**html:**

```
<div id="logo">
    <a>&nbsp;ROBERT WATKINS&nbsp;</a>
</div>
<div id="navigation" class="link">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="biography.html">BIOGRAPHY</a></li>
        <li><a href="painting.html">PAINTING</a></li>
        <li><a href="drawing.html">DRAWING</a></li>
        <li><a href="photography.html">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
        <li><a href="teaching.html">TEACHING</a></li>
        <li><a href="writing.html">WRITING</a></li>
        <li><a href="links.html">LINKS</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#navigation{
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    left: 150px;
    z-index: 10
}

#navigation ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navigation ul li{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#navigation li a{
    padding-right: 18px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

First wrap your logo and nav in a div and give that a specific width. Let's say like 960px.

```
#logo{
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid white;
    outline-width: 5px;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", "sans-serif";
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-transform: none;
    color: white;
    margin: 7px 0 0 8px;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

#navigation{
    z-index: 10;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

Hope that helps. I haven't tested in IE but it seems to work in Chrome and FF. Might have to adjust padding and margins for positioning.

Comment: No problem! Glad I was able to help.